# What are the Rahasyas mentioned in Vedas?

Tags: vedas, tantra, dattatreya

As per Vedas, the Rahasyas are mentioned in the same breath as other sacred scriptures like Itihasas, Puranas and Vedas.

> "In this way all the Vedas are manifested along with the kalpas,**rahasyas**, Brahmanas, Upanishads, Itihas, anvakhyatas and the puranas." - Gopatha Brahman purva 2:10.

Is this a reference to Tantras (many are titled "Rahasya")? Or to scriptures like **Shiva Rahasya**, **Preta Manjari**, Dattatreya's **Tripura Rahasya and Avadhoot Gita** which are part of extended Tantric tradition?

[image]